# Vector orthogonal to another vector and coplanar to two others

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Let $\underline v = h\underline i+l\underline j-3\underline k=(h, l, -3)$, $\underline w=\underline i-\underline j-\underline k=(1, -1, -1)$, $\underline t=\underline i-\underline k=(1, 0, -1)$ and $\underline s=\underline i+\underline j=(1, 1, 0)$. For which values of $h$ and $l$ is $\underline v$ orthogonal to $\underline s$ and coplanar to $\underline w$ and $\underline t$?

1. for all pairs of $h$ and $l$ satisfying $h=-l$;
2. for only one pair $(h, l)$ in which $h$ satisfies $h^3-4h^2+9=0$;
3. for infinite pairs $(h, l)$; in one of them $h=0$ and $l=2$;
4. for only one pair $(h, l)$ in which $h$ satisfies $h^3+2h^2+9=0$;
5. No one of previous answers.

**My attempt.** The condition that $\underline v$ is coplanar to $\underline w$ and $\underline t$ implies that there exist coefficients $a$ and $b$ such that
$$
\underline v = a\underline w + b\underline t=a(1, -1, -1)+b(1, 0, -1)=(a+b, -a, -a-b).
$$
So $(a+b, -a,-a-b)=(h, l, -3)$, from which we get
$$
a = -l, \quad b = h+l,\quad h = 3.
$$ 
The condition that $\underline v$ is orthogonal to $\underline s$ implies that
$$
\underline v\cdot\underline s =h+l=0,
$$
that is $h=-l$.

So, I think that the correct answer is $1$. Is this attempt correct?

**Edit.** Also probably answer $2$ can be the correct one. Because if $h=3$ necesserely $l=-3$.

Comment: option 1 is not correct since it states "for all pairs", but the condition are true only for one pair

Comment: Yes. Indeed there is only one pair, that is $(3, -3)$. Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, the condition that $\underline v$ is orthogonal to $\underline s$ implies that
$$
\underline v\cdot\underline s =h+l=0,
$$
that is $h=-l$.

For the condition to be coplanar to $\underline w$ and $\underline t$ we can use cross product that is

$$n=w\times t=(1,0,1)$$

and by dot product

$$v \cdot n = (h,-h,-3)\cdot (1,0,1)=h-3=0\implies h=3$$

Thus the correct one should be the option $2$.